# What is a "half latch" in an FPGA?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx, radiation

In a paper about radiation hard FPGAs I came across this sentence:

> "Another concern regarding Virtex devices is half latches. Half
> latches are sometimes used within these devices for internal
> constants, as this is more efficient than using logic".

I have never heard about an FPGA device primitive called a "half latch".
As far as I understand, it sounds like a hidden mechanism to "source" a constant '0' or '1' in the backend tools...
Can anyone explain what exactly a "half latch" is, especially in the context of FPGAs, and how they can be used to save logic?

EDIT: The paper where I found this was [A Comparison of Radiation-Hard and Radiation-Tolerant FPGAs for Space Applications](https://nepp.nasa.gov/docuploads/3C8F70A3-2452-4336-B70CDF1C1B08F805/JPL%20Rad-Tolerant%20FPGAs%20for%20Space%20Applications.pdf)

Comment: Which search engine did you use?

Comment: It's a fault that is reported in the design stage that requires corrective action https://www.slideserve.com/delilah/single-event-upsets-in-sram-fpgas  due to accelerated stress, like a bit error internally except it latches and can make a tristate into an output for example

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Faults are used for internal constants? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: No. Half-latches are hidden faults that must be avoided.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That still doesn't make any sense in context. The presentation you linked to clearly depicts a "half latch" as a part of the FPGA, alongside other things like "config bits" and "BRAM". It isn't a fault; it's something which can be _affected by_ a fault.

Comment: They are design faults because a weak positive feedback creates a fault from a port going into tristate getting latched so Verilog reports them as half-latch faults then you have do low level diagnosis to prevent them

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I'm sorry, but that still isn't correct. Half-latches are not the same thing as _inferred_ latches, which may cause a synthesis _warning_ (not "fault"). A "fault" in the context of the presentation you linked is an electrical upset -- caused by a radiation event, for instance -- which disrupts logic running on the FPGA.

Comment: @duskwolf I was never referring to inferred latches, rather the same item described by Dmitry

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A half-latch is a gate with positive feedback implemented with a weak pull-up transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3BvCa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the input is actively driven, it overrides the signal coming from the weak pullup. When the input is in Z-state, the weak pullup can keep the logical "1" at the input (and "0" at the output) indefinitely. It will not keep the opposite state reliably, hence "half-latch".

Why would someone want a half-latch instead of a full latch? For some signals it doesn't make sense to be able to store both constants. For example, a D-flipflop can have `enable` input only latched high, and `reset` input only latched low, otherwise it will simply be eliminated during synthesis. That's the kind of signals for which half-latches are used: they are either latched to default value, or driven by interconnect.

Comment: So you're supposed to drive the input high for a moment before floating it, or you will end up with a metastable state that will eventually but unpredictably flip?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, the FPGA drives all half-latches before each programming cycle.

Comment: That sounds like a significant complication of whichever circuitry supplies the input, just to save a single transistor. If you could write something about why on earth that would be worth it, I think it would improve the answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Why do you think a half-latches only save a single transistor? AFAIK they are used as constants which otherwise would have to be encoded in LUTs.

Comment: A fully functional latch would only need a single weak NMOS in addition to your diagram to pull the input down when the output is high, right? I don't know what a LUT is -- can you say something in your answer about how "used as constants" works if the only thing it can store reliably is an 1? How are these things _used_?

Comment: @HenningMakholm LUT is an acronym for look-up table. I have added an example.

Comment: @HenningMakholm And BTW, if you use a full latch, you still have to drive it once to get it into a predictable state, right?

Comment: Ah, so if I understand you correctly, this is for use in a case where in the design phase you can _either_ connect the input signal (in which case you're supposed to be driving it _all the time_ rather than sometimes tri-stating it), _or_ leave it unconnected entirely, in which case the half-latch supplies a default?

Comment: (At first your description sounded to me like the input was supposed to be something like a tri-state common line where some of the time nobody might be driving it).

Comment: @Dimitry: Nice answer. Do I understand correctly, that half latches are (commonly?) used in FPGA interconnect matrices? And by sourcing constant from "within" the interconnect matrices no logic resources must be used.

Comment: @damage Exactly.

Answer (score -2):

It seems they provide the logic for keeping constants.

Since they are not observable, can only be initialised once (so only reconfigurable after device initialisation), they do not consume a full LUT and they are much simpler, nevertheless usefull.

Comment: I saw that abstract text when I searched google, too. It doesn't properly explain them as per OP's question, nor lead them to a datasheet example. Downvoting.

Comment: If its a different structure of the FPGA and less than a full LUT,  with a few more more specifics, then please explain how it does not answer the question 'what is it' and as for 'how it saves logic', that's also answered.